# jslint error..Don't make functions within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

In the below piece of code I am getting the JSLint error (Don't make functions within a loop). can you help me to modify the code to satisfy the JSLint.

```
setEllipsis : function () {
    $('.co_documentReportTable > thead > tr > th').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.co_dcrTable_Header').each(function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            if($el.css("overflow") === "hidden") {
                var text = $el.html();
                while ($el.height() > 64) {
                    $el.text(function (index, text) {
                        return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
                    });
                    //
                    var txt = 'Fair consideration/no fraudulent conveyance';
                    if(text.indexOf(txt) !== -1 ) {
                        $el.text(txt + '...');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I tried creating another function and calling it then in that case while loop is getting executed forever.

Comment: this is for multiline and above code works but am getting jslint error how to resolve the jslint error ?

Comment: Search for `[javascript] closure loop` here on SO.

Comment: Just disable that rule. It hardly applies here.

Answer (score 3):

Looks in general like you want to use the text-overflow: ellipses CSS property instead here.

Otherwise - pull the anonymous function up and give it a name, so you might end up with :

```
setEllipsis : function () {
    var addEllipses = function(index, text) {
        return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
    };

    $('.co_documentReportTable > thead > tr > th').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.co_dcrTable_Header').each(function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            if($el.css("overflow") === "hidden")
            {
                var text = $el.html();
                while ($el.height() > 64) {
                    $el.text(addEllipses);
                    var txt = 'Fair consideration/no fraudulent conveyance';
                    if(text.indexOf(txt) !== -1 ){
                        $el.text(txt + '...');
                    }
                }
            }           
        });
    });
}
```